# Can I use TypeORM @JoinColumn without the double underscores?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, express, typeorm, entity-relationship

I have 2 entities (so far) with a ManyToOne relationship between the Posts and the User (the order came this way because the user entity existed first and the post entity was created afterward before I joined the company).

```
@Entity()
export class Post {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column()
    text: string;

    @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.id, { eager: true })
    @JoinColumn({
        name: 'userid' // if I try to do user here it'll break too
    })
    user: Promise<User>;
}

@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string | undefined;

    @Column()
    first_name: string | undefined;

    @Column()
    last_name: string | undefined;

    @Column()
    email: string | undefined;
}
```

So the code relating to these entities works fine, however when you fetch Posts the response always sees `__user__` in the object instead of just `user`.

If I try manipulate the date it really slows down the performance to a degree that am trying to avoid. Is there anyway to create this relation/retrieve the information without __

I have tried to map over the relations:

```
return posts.map(sector => {
  const { __user__, ...rest } = post; // __user__ doesn't exist on type of Post
  return {
    ...rest,
    user: __user__
  };
});
```

What confuses me is that if the double underscore doesn't exist on the Entity (which it doesn't) why would it be created with that structure and pass the Type check